# Hoare partition scheme may cause infinite recursion

Tags: sorting, quicksort

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Quicksort&oldid=859050195#Hoare_partition_scheme) states: "...partitioning algorithm guarantees lo ≤ p < hi which implies both resulting partitions are non-empty, hence there's no risk of infinite recursion."

What prevents Hoare partition from not returning j equal to hi?
If our pivot is max number, we may execute j <- j – 1 only once and exit with j=hi

```
E.g. A= [2,0]
```

Some [implementations](https://stackabuse.com/quicksort-in-python) add a final swap of placing the initially chosen pivot into returned j:

```
swap A[lo] with A[j]
return j
```

What would guarantee p < hi?

Full pseudo-code from wiki:

```
algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
    pivot := A[lo]
    i := lo - 1
    j := hi + 1
    loop forever
        do
            i := i + 1
        while A[i] < pivot

        do
            j := j - 1 <------------- execute once
        while A[j] > pivot

        if i >= j then
            return j <------------- exit

        swap A[i] with A[j]
```

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Please [include in your question post everything needed to invite useful answers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (such as what $lo, p, hi$ and $j$ may be) - hyperlinks welcome for reference&detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice the outer loop, `loop forever`?

---

Let us say in the first iteration of that `loop forever` loop, we have just finished the second inner loop, `do j := j - 1 while A[j] > pivot`.

- If `j := j-1` has been executed at least twice, then `j <= (hi+1)-2 = hi-1`.
- Otherwise `j := j-1` has been executed exactly once. Then
  $\quad\quad$`j = (hi+1)-1 = hi`.
  Note that the first inner loop, `do i := i + 1 while A[i] < pivot` produces
  $\quad\quad$ `i = lo`
  since `i = lo - 1` initially and `A[lo] = pivot`.

  Now we execute `if i >= j then return j`. Since the condition `i >= j` does not hold as `lo < hi` (the pseudocode for quicksort specifies that only when `lo < hi` shall partition be performed), the code `return j` will be skipped, i.e., we shall go on with the next iteration of that `loop forever` loop. In that next iteration, `j := j-1` will be executed again, causing `j < hi`.

So, we will always have `j < hi` at some point of time during the partition. Since `j` would never increase, we will have `j < hi` when we `return j`. $\quad\checkmark$

---

The analysis above holds regardless of whether our pivot is the max number or not.

Comment: On the 1st iteration of the outer loop <i> always stays equal to <lo>. That means the outer loop will be executed 2 or more times. Never once. Thank you, John L. It closes my gap with different variations (old Cormen) where it starts rolling <j> prior to <i>